# how to repeat arrayllist data in java netbeans

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans

I want to repeat data from arraylist in java netbenas one by one by pressing jbutton. so i want to know how repeat data from single array list following my code

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private List<String>numbers;
private ListIterator <String>ltr;

public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
numbers=newArraylist<>();
numbers.add("A");
numbers.add("b");
numbers.add("c");

ltr= numbers.Listinterator();
}
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   
ltr.hasnext()
{
system.out.println(ltr.next());}}
```

out put need to come like

> AbcAbc

Comment: Also you can use `new ArrayList(oldList)`.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think you misread question. List contains `A`, `b`, and `c`, and OP want to print "next" value from list on each button push, wrapping around as needed, so successive button pushes will print `A`, `b`, `c`, `A`, `b`, `c`, `A`, `b`, `c`, ...

Comment: @Andreas Clarity is a wonderful thing - still learnt something though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want iterator to start over from the beginning when it reaches the end, you need to create a new `Iterator`, e.g.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (! ltr.hasNext())
        ltr = numbers.listInterator();
    System.out.println(ltr.next()); // Prints next or first element
}
```

As an alternative, since its an `ArrayList`, you can use indexes to access elements, and wrap the index around using the `%` modulus operator, e.g.

```
private int listIdx;
```

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    System.out.println(numbers.get(listIdx++ % numbers.size()));
}
```

Or use an `if` statement:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    System.out.println(numbers.get(listIdx));
    if (++listIdx == numbers.size())
        listIdx = 0;
}
```